# how to fix collider offset when using rigging animation with navmesh agent

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, agent

When i use rigging and navhmesh agent, i have this problem with animation. My collider going a little bit slower from enemy speed as a result, collider stays back. How can i fix it? If i use normal animation without rig builder it works good, but with rigging i can do much better animation.

I already tried to make children-parents etc. I looked everywhere on web and didnt find something to fix it. The only thing that i found, i thing was saying that it was a bug.

[Photo of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZEro.png)

Answer (score 0):

I fix it. The solution is simple. It is a bug. If anyone has the same problem you should make all the animation at once. If you make the animation and then try to make any changes, it is going to destroy your animation and bug it.